# How to remove a long line with special characters from a big file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file having 200 lines and I want to remove 5 long lines( each line contains special characters).

```
$cat abc
............
comments[asci?_203] part of jobs where to delete
5 similar lines
.....
```

I tried sed to remove these 5 lines, using line numbers(nl) on the file, but did not work.
Thanks

Comment: You provided insufficient information. 1. How do you define _long line_? 2. How do you define _special character_? 3. Are there long lines without special characters or shorter lines with special characters? 4. What exactly did you try, and what was the output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the lines with awk? This is untested with special characters, but *maybe* it could work

```
awk '{if (length($0)<55) print $0}' < abc
```

Replace `55` with the maximum line length you want to keep